# How to fix KDE NEON User Edition errors and update to Plasma 6

Tags: apt, upgrade, kde

Yesterday KDE team released KDE 6.0.0 and added it to User Edition of KDE NEON. I'm using it like year or so and want to hop to this shiny new release. But have a problem with `apt full-update`, even if says that there is 7 problems it can perfom update but it breaks everything (I've tried and rolled back)

```
# apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 7
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 7
Investigating (0) plasma-desktop:amd64 < 4:5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build47 @ii umH Ib >
Broken plasma-desktop:amd64 Depends on plasma-desktop-data:amd64 < 4:5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build47 -> 4:6.0.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build52 @ii umU > (= 4:5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build47)
  Considering plasma-desktop-data:amd64 104 as a solution to plasma-desktop:amd64 5310
  Added plasma-desktop-data:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing plasma-desktop:amd64 via keep of plasma-desktop-data:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (0) plasma-desktop-data:amd64
Investigating (0) kwrite:amd64 < 4:23.08.4-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build29 -> 4:24.02.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build31 @ii umU Ib >
Broken kwrite:amd64 Breaks on kate5-data:amd64 < 4:23.08.4-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build29 @ii mK >
  Considering kate5-data:amd64 -2 as a solution to kwrite:amd64 102
  Added kate5-data:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 4:23.08.3-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build28 for kate5-data but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 4:23.08.2-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build27 for kate5-data but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1 for kate5-data but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing kwrite:amd64 via remove of kate5-data:amd64
Investigating (0) liblayershellqtinterface6:amd64 < none -> 6.0.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build34 @un uN Ib >
Broken liblayershellqtinterface6:amd64 Breaks on liblayershellqtinterface5:amd64 < 5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build32 @ii mK IPb > (< 6.0.0)
  Considering liblayershellqtinterface5:amd64 -1 as a solution to liblayershellqtinterface6:amd64 36
  Added liblayershellqtinterface5:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.27.9-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build31 for liblayershellqtinterface5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.27.8-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build30 for liblayershellqtinterface5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1 for liblayershellqtinterface5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.24.4-0ubuntu1 for liblayershellqtinterface5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing liblayershellqtinterface6:amd64 via remove of liblayershellqtinterface5:amd64
Investigating (0) kf6-baloowidgets:amd64 < none -> 4:24.02.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build32 @un uN Ib >
Broken kf6-baloowidgets:amd64 Breaks on libkf5baloowidgets-bin:amd64 < 4:23.08.4-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build25 @ii mK > (< 4:24.02)
  Considering libkf5baloowidgets-bin:amd64 -3 as a solution to kf6-baloowidgets:amd64 4
  Added libkf5baloowidgets-bin:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1 for libkf5baloowidgets-bin but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing kf6-baloowidgets:amd64 via remove of libkf5baloowidgets-bin:amd64
Investigating (0) libappstreamqt5-3:amd64 < none -> 1.0.2-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build43 @un uN Ib >
Broken libappstreamqt5-3:amd64 Breaks on libappstreamqt2:amd64 < 0.16.2-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build40 @ii mK >
  Considering libappstreamqt2:amd64 -1 as a solution to libappstreamqt5-3:amd64 3
  Added libappstreamqt2:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 0.15.2-2 for libappstreamqt2 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Fixing libappstreamqt5-3:amd64 via remove of libappstreamqt2:amd64
Investigating (0) libkimageannotator0:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libkimageannotator0:amd64 Depends on libkimageannotator-common:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 -> 0.7.0-0xneon1+22.04+jammy+release+build3 @ii umU > (= 0.5.3-1)
  Considering libkimageannotator-common:amd64 -1 as a solution to libkimageannotator0:amd64 0
  Added libkimageannotator-common:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libkimageannotator0:amd64 via keep of libkimageannotator-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (0) libkimageannotator-common:amd64
Re-Instated libkimageannotator-common:amd64 (1 vs 1)
Investigating (1) libkimageannotator0:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libkimageannotator0:amd64 Depends on libkimageannotator-common:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 -> 0.7.0-0xneon1+22.04+jammy+release+build3 @ii umU > (= 0.5.3-1)
  Considering libkimageannotator-common:amd64 -1 as a solution to libkimageannotator0:amd64 0
  Added libkimageannotator-common:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libkimageannotator0:amd64 via keep of libkimageannotator-common:amd64
Investigating (2) libkimageannotator-qt6-0:amd64 < none -> 0.7.0-0xneon1+22.04+jammy+release+build3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libkimageannotator-qt6-0:amd64 Conflicts on libkimageannotator-common:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 | 0.7.0-0xneon1+22.04+jammy+release+build3 @ii umH > (< 0.7)
  Considering libkimageannotator-common:amd64 -1 as a solution to libkimageannotator-qt6-0:amd64 1
  Added libkimageannotator-common:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libkimageannotator-qt6-0:amd64 via remove of libkimageannotator-common:amd64
Investigating (2) libkimageannotator0:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libkimageannotator0:amd64 Depends on libkimageannotator-common:amd64 < 0.5.3-1 | 0.7.0-0xneon1+22.04+jammy+release+build3 @ii umR > (= 0.5.3-1)
  Considering libkimageannotator-common:amd64 1 as a solution to libkimageannotator0:amd64 0
  Removing libkimageannotator0:amd64 rather than change libkimageannotator-common:amd64
Done
Entering ResolveByKeep
```

Update using `pkcon` not event happened. It stops before actually update something with error

```
# pkcon update
Getting updates                         [=========================]         
Finished                                [=========================]         
Testing changes                         [=========================]         
Finished                                [=========================]         
Fatal error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  plasma-desktop: Depends: plasma-desktop-data (= 4:5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build47)
```

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    *FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encounter the same problem today.

After `sudo apt full-upgrade`, You can try my workaround for fixing dependency:

Install libdecor-0-0 dependency for libsdl2-2.0-0 and mark it automatically installed.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade libdecor-0-0
sudo apt-mark auto libdecor-0-0
```

Install libsdl2-2.0-0 dependency for plasma-desktop-data and mark it automatically installed.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade libsdl2-2.0-0
sudo apt-mark auto libsdl2-2.0-0
```

Find version of dependency that pkcon is complaining about, and install it.

```
sudo apt-cache showpkg plasma-desktop-data
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop-data=4:5.27.10-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build47
```

Finally, run `pkcon update` again.

Note that if you attempts to reboot after `sudo apt full-upgrade`, desktop is not fully functional.

In case you reboot, it should work partially, you can use shortcut to open konsole and restore your backup.

Remember to backup before big update.